# Search list of datetime for open time slot

Tags: c#, datetime

Given a list of objects containing a start and end time search to see if an input datetime start and end fall in the timespan of any of the elements in the list.

ie. 8:30-9:30, 10:00-12:00, 12:30-1:00, 1:30-2:30, 2:30-4:00

I've played with:
    testPlans.Where(plan => plan.p_startDateTime >= startDate || plan.p_endDateTime <= endDate)

but I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried using `&&` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. Improvements always welcome.

```
if(testPlans.Where(plan =>  startDate >= plan.p_startDateTime && endDate <= plan.p_endDateTime).Count() > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(testPlans.Where(plan =>  startDate > plan.p_startDateTime && startDate < plan.p_endDateTime).Count() > 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(testPlans.Where(plan =>  endDate > plan.p_startDateTime && endDate < plan.p_endDateTime).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `testPlans.Where(ef => ef.p_endDateTime > startDate).All(fe => fe.p_startDateTime > endDate)` is a little shorter.